# How to compare a specific part of one (Ip adress) with other ip adreess in another column in RDD python pyspark without using collect() and for loop

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

I have two lists of Ip addresses which are located in separate txt files.
I want to make a comparison between these two data sets by taking the first three bytes of them.

For example:

```
a='123.43.54.231'
b='123.43.54.50'
```

since the first three bytes are mutual between a and b then i want to pick up the full a (`123.43.54.231`).

since I deal with RDD, then `collect()` should be avoided as possible considering it's large dataset. Actually, i wrote a correct code that does what i want. However, what i did contained `collect()` which contribute to make the process incredibly slow.

## Python_3.7.3

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

  if __name__ == "__main__":
  conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Big_Data_Project").setMaster("local[*]")
  sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
  
  Ip_1= sc.textFile("Ip_1.txt")

#Ip_1='''123.34.405.123 153.74.61.65 43.34.65.123 ...... '''
#Ip_2='''123.34.321.143 153.74.61.43 43.34.65.112 ...... '''

  Ip_2= sc.textFile("Ip_2.txt")

  y=[]
  def func():
      
      for i in Ip_1.collect():
          for x in Ip_2.collect():
              d=i[:i.rfind(".")]
              h=x[:x.rfind(".")]
              if d==h:
                  y.append(i)
              else:
                  pass
      return y
  Wanted_Ip=sc.parallelize(func())
  Wanted_Ip.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("My Ip List")
```

as I explained, I want to get the **full** `ip_adress` of Ip_1 that are matching with the first three bytes of the Ip_2 RDD which are

```
153.74.61.65
43.34.65.123
```

I am searching for a solution that **does not include `collect()`**.

Comment: It's historically understandable the relation between RDDs and methods like collect or toLocalIterator, but it's not a general truth that when working with RDDs, collect method has to be avoided as possible. This sort of assertions are not appropriate in general.  The problem is with large datasets because the data is brought at driver memory level from all partitions collected into the driver side. If the driver can store the largest of those partition, then toLocalIterator can be used instead cf. github.com/.../python/pyspark/rdd.py repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to generate a key to join on, and then perform the join :

```py
gen_key = lambda x : (x.rsplit('.', 1)[0], x)
Ip_1 = Ip_1.map(gen_key)
Ip_2 = Ip_2.map(gen_key)
common_ip = Ip_1.join(Ip_2)
```

common_ip is a rdd where each line is a (key,value) pair with :

- key = the 3 digit ip
- value = a pair of IPs from Ip_1 and Ip_2

```py
common_ip.collect()                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

[('123.43.54', ('123.43.54.231', '123.43.54.50'))]
```

If you just want the Ip_1's IPs, then you can do :

```
common_ip.map(lambda x : x[1][0]).repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("My Ip List")
```

Comment: Do you know why when i write : 
gen_key = lambda x : (x.rsplit('.', -3)[0], x)
it does not take the first three bytes!. i want to take them from left to right not from right to left. There is another information inculdes different number of dots on the right side.

Comment: there are 2 functions : `split` and `rsplit` (reverse split). The number is how many split do you want, not how many characters... Therefore, use `x.split('.')[0]`